# Gray scale cross browser

Tags: css3

Pessoal estou querendo colocar um filter grayscale em algumas imagens ele funciona somente no Google chrome e no Opera e não funciona no Mozila e nem no Safari.

Segue o css:

```
.parceiros li a img{
    margin-top: 5%;
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);    
   -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);    
   -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);    
   -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
   }


.parceiros li a img:hover{
     -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);    
   -moz-filter: grayscale(0);    
   -ms-filter: grayscale(0);    
   -o-filter: grayscale(0);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente assim:

```
.parceiros li a img{ 
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
  filter: gray;  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
  -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
}

.parceiros li a img:hover { 
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: none;
}
```

*Pode modificar ou remover o tempo da transição, coloque .6s de exemplo;*

[Exemplo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffersonalison/ydaun7u1/2/)

Comment: entao edeitei o meu post esqueci de colocar o hover e assim funciono o seu metodo porem ainda sim o safari nao aceitou e o mozila aceitou porem nao funciona o hover

Comment: Testa agora ai.

Comment: ai sim amigo funciono o hover que faltava porem o unico que nao aceitou nada ainda  foi o safari o mozila tava faltando porem esta pegando mais o safari nao tem alguma ideia do que possa ser

Comment: Que SO e qual Versão do safari esta usando? Fiz os testes aqui no OS X Yosemite com o Safari 8.0, funcionou normalmente pois ele usa o prefixo -webkit.

Comment: uso so windows e o safari 5.1.7

Comment: Hum.. é a versão do seu Safari. A propriedade filter do css, da suporte a 7+ http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: Da uma olhada ai: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685794/grayscale-image-with-css-on-safari-5-x

Comment: ata entendi entao de qualquer forma funcionou aqui brigadao de novo =3

Comment: De nada (Y) até mais!